# Multiple MAVEN modules sharing a common source folder

Tags: maven, compilation, package

A central POM defines multiple JAR modules what must package parts of a central, common source folder. This is a legacy project and I want to keep the source files in one single place. Is it possible to set up MAVEN to **compile and package** only parts of this source folder?

SK

Comment: Have you tried configuration options of the maven-compiler-plugin? Can you paste such sections of your parent pom?

Comment: Hi, yes, the compiler-plugin is the solution in this case. Thank you WiLL. SK

Comment: You might consider posting an answer when you solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this is the solution:

```
...
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>../src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.build.helper.maven.plugin}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>sk/maven/api/**/*.*</source>
                            <source>sk/ext/lib/**/*.*</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven.compile.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <includes>
                    <include>sk/maven/api/**/*.*</include>
                    <include>sk/ext/lib/**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>sk/maven/api/**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```